Rational points on an elliptic curve the denominator of x is a square
Let $f \in \mathbb Q[x]$ be a squarefree cubic polynomial with nonzero constant coefficient and consider the elliptic curve $E : y^2 = f(x)$.
Define $E(\mathbb Q)' \subseteq E(\mathbb Q)$ as
$$\left \lbrace (x,y)\in E(\mathbb Q)  \mid Denominator(x) \text{ is a square}\right \rbrace.$$
My question is whether $E(\mathbb Q)'$ is always finite?
This is a question that seems to be halfway in between rational points on elliptic curves and rational points on hyperelliptic curves. Since if we impose the additional condition that $Numerator(x)$ is a square, then $x$ itself is a square and we are looking for rational points on the genus 2 curve $y^2=f(z^2)$. And the set of rational points on a genus 2 curve is known to be finite.
The reason for the nonzero constant coefficient is that otherwise one could chose $f$ such that $y^2=f(z^2)$ is a genus 1 curve with infinitely many rational points, leading to an example where $E(\mathbb Q)'$ is infinite.

If $f$ is monic with integer coefficients, then for all rational points $(x,y)$, $x$ must have square denominator, just by comparing $p$-adic valuations of $x$ and $y$ at primes in the denominators.

Thanks, this made me realize I asked the wrong question.
